Airflow running on Docker - write output file
I am learning Airflow with Docker and I have some issues. I am on a windows machine.
I have a Dag with python and bash operators. the python operator makes an API call and the bash operator writes the output to a file.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
import requests
import json
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import os
# Define the task to get a cat fact
def get_cat_fact():

    try:
        response = requests.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
        cat_fact_json = response.json()
        fact = cat_fact_json['fact']
        length = cat_fact_json['length']
        output_text = f'Cat Fact: {fact}, Length: {length}'
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        output_text = 'Unable to make api call'
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
    print(output_text)
    return output_text

# Define default_args for DAG

my_default_args = {
    'owner': 'ecronin'
}

# Create the DAG instance
with DAG(
        dag_id='cat_fact_api_dag',
        start_date=datetime(2024, 8, 5),  
        schedule = '@daily',
        catchup = False,
        description = 'call api, write file',
        tags = ['crlakehouse'],
        default_args = my_default_args
        ):

    # Create a PythonOperator to run the get_cat_fact function
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_cat_fact',
        python_callable=get_cat_fact,
        do_xcom_push=True
    )

    # Create a BashOperator to echo the cat fact into a file
    task2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command='echo "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=\'get_cat_fact\',       key=\'return_value\') }}" > $AIRFLOW_HOME/tmp/output.txt'
    )

task1 >> task2

`
I ran the command: docker exec -it f3dafe5f8edb sh, which is the Webserver image. Verified that $AIRFLOW_HOME = /opt/Airflow. I manually created dir tmp with permissions 775.
I am running everything directly in VS Code terminal.
My bash task fails to run with error: [2024-08-06, 19:42:21 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /usr/bin/bash: line 1: /opt/***/tmp/output.txt: No such file or directory
I changed the path to /opt/Airflow/output.txt. The bash task does complete, but there is no file in the airflow directory. I guess I'm completely wrong about where the file is being written or how to find it. Any information will help. Also, I don't have much container experience.
Update: I added the following script:
def check_directory():
import os
dir_path = os.environ.get('AIRFLOW_HOME', '/opt/airflow') + 
'/tmp'
print(f"Does directory {dir_path} exist? 
{os.path.exists(dir_path)}")
print(f"Directory listing: {os.listdir(dir_path if 
os.path.exists(dir_path) else '/opt/airflow')}")

When I look at the log for this task, I see the following:
INFO - Directory listing: ['logs', 'dags', 'config', 'plugins', 'webserver_config.py', '***.cfg', 'output.txt']
So, now I know it has been written but still don't understand where it is and how to find it.
